# AWS Amplify: How to switch aws profile that amplify env is pointing to

Tags: aws-amplify

I started an Amplify project using:

```
amplify init
```

I created an environment named `env` and chose AWS profile `default`.

It seems like `env` is pointing to the `default` profile. Is there any way for me to make `env` pointing to different AWS profile?

For example, if I have two profiles:

1. default
2. personal

Can I make `env` point to the `personal` AWS profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is a couple of years old, but I had a similar issue and came across it.

The relevant configuration is in `<your-project>/amplify/.config/local-aws-info.json`, which will look  something like this:

```json
// <your-project>/amplify/.config/local-aws-info.json
{
  "develop": {
    "configLevel": "project",
    "useProfile": true,
    "profileName": "SomeNamedProfile"
  },
  "main": {
    "configLevel": "project",
    "useProfile": true,
    "profileName": "SomeOtherNamedProfile"
  }
}
```

Changing the value of `profileName` to specify a different AWS CLI profile worked without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

`amplify configure project` will give you the option to update/remove a profile that amplify is using